# I have a good enough command of English to communicate

Tags: sentence-structure

Does it sound natural to say

> I have a good enough command of English to communicate.

Since it is about the skills of using English language, it would not be impressive to make mistake at the first place.

What are other ways to say  your level is average or slightly better than average at English overall.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple.

> **I can communicate well in English**.

The more unnecessary words you add to your sentence the less natural it sounds.